# QNetworkAccessManager doesnt emit finished signal

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to multiple request with QNetworkAccessManager even  I connect slots QNetworkAccessManager cant emit finished() signal.

Here is the code I implemented.

```
void GetNetwork::getAction(QStringList *urls, QList<QByteArray> *result)
{
    uint size=urls->size();

    multiGetResult=result;
    getUrls=urls;
    setFlags();

    for(uint x=0;x<size;x++)
    {
        int test=caluculateIndex(x);
       getNAM[test]->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(urls->at(x))));
    }


    //qDebug()<<reply->readAll();

    while (!waitWithFlag())  QThread::msleep(15);

    delete threadFlag;
}

bool GetNetwork::setMultipleGet(uint number)
{
    int diff=number-(getNAM.size()-1);

    if(((getNAM.size()-1)+diff)<0)
        return false;

    for(int i=0;i<diff;i++)
    {
        getNAM.append(new QNetworkAccessManager(this));
        connect(getNAM[getNAM.size()-1],SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(handleMultiRequest(QNetworkReply*)));
    }

    for(int i=diff;i<0;i++)
    {
        disconnect(getNAM[getNAM.size()-1],SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(handleMultiRequest(QNetworkReply*)));
        delete getNAM[getNAM.size()-1];
        getNAM.remove(getNAM.size()-1);
    }
    return true;
}

void GetNetwork::handleMultiRequest(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    int index=getUrls->indexOf(reply->url().toString());

    if(reply->error()!=QNetworkReply::NoError||index==-1)
    {
        QString error=QString("Network Error file:%1 line:%2 error:%3")
                             .arg(__FILE__)
                             .arg(__LINE__)
                             .arg(reply->errorString());

        emit errorOccured(error);
        return;
    }

    multiGetResult->insert(index,reply->readAll());
    threadFlag[index]=true;
}
```

What's wrong in these codes? I cant figure it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to hook the error signal?

Comment: You must return to the event loop to have the request being executed  and the result being reported. Your code with the while loop and sleep looks like you block the event loop (until the result arrived?), thus the request isn't executed at all.

Comment: I.e., sleep() blocks the event loop and thus any event processing including network I/O. Also in a UI application, sleep() in the main thread is really bad practice, as it makes the UI unresponsive.

Comment: no it waits untill all threads  are done. but qnetworkaccessmanager doesnt emit finished signal and the function waits here for nothing.i just want to be sure that all gets are done end of the function.

Comment: the problem is about while "(!waitWithFlag())  QThread::msleep(10);" end of the function is there a way wait these gets until all of them are done?

Comment: @VeyselBekirMacit Are you running different instances of QNetworkAccessManager in different threads.

Comment: @adnankamili no different instances of QNetworkAccessManager in same thread(I call them same fucntion in getAction())

Comment: @VeyselBekirMacit connect(getNAM[getNAM.size()-1] only connecting one instance of QNetworkAccessManager (the last one)

Comment: @adnankamili yes I connect QNetworkAccessManager there. but the problem is here "(!waitWithFlag()) QThread::msleep(10);" when I delete it,QNetworkAccessManager can emit finished signal but function must wait there until all get funtion I call are done.How can I do that I need something like QFutureSynchronizer for ordinary fucntion?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld do you know something instead of sleep() because problem is there like you said.

Comment: The cleanest way to continue with what you want to do after the finished() is to put it into a slot connected to finished().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need a separate thread for QNetworkAccessManager as it internally runs in a separate thread (asynchronous) since Qt 4.8.1.

Secondly you are only connecting the last instance of QNetworkAccessManager with a finished slot, instead of doing that, connect each instance of QNetworkAccessManager with handleMultiRequest Slot and keep increasing the count whenever the slot is invoked. You don't need sleep and all that stuff, it is all event driven.
So,

```
void GetNetwork::handleMultiRequest(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    int index=getUrls->indexOf(reply->url().toString());

    if(reply->error()!=QNetworkReply::NoError||index==-1)
    {
        QString error=QString("Network Error file:%1 line:%2 error:%3")
                             .arg(__FILE__)
                             .arg(__LINE__)
                             .arg(reply->errorString());

        emit errorOccured(error);
        return;
    }

    count++;
   if(count == num_get_requests)
   {
       emit
         allDone()
   }
}
```

Comment: QNetworkAccessManager can have more than 6 thread run at sametime?

Comment: @VeyselBekirMacit That is for HttpPipelining, those six threads are for the same request. you can disable that feature programatically,

Answer (score 0):

and I changed fucntions like Adnan idea

```
void GetNetwork::handleMultiRequest(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    int index=getUrls->indexOf(reply->url().toString());

    if(reply->error()!=QNetworkReply::NoError||index==-1)
    {
        QString error=QString("Network Error file:%1 line:%2 error:%3")
                             .arg(__FILE__)
                             .arg(__LINE__)
                             .arg(reply->errorString());

        emit errorOccured(error);
        return;
    }

    multiGetResult->insert(index,reply->readAll());
    threadDoneCounter++;
    if(threadDoneCounter==getUrls->size())
        emit threadsAreDone();
}
```

and

```
void GetNetwork::getAction(QStringList *urls, QList<QByteArray> *result)
{
    uint size=urls->size();

    multiGetResult=result;
    getUrls=urls;
    threadDoneCounter=0;

    for(uint x=0;x<size;x++)
    {
        int test=caluculateIndex(x);
       getNAM[test]->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(urls->at(x))));
    }



    QEventLoop eLoop;
    connect(this,SIGNAL(threadsAreDone()),&eLoop,SLOT(quit()));
    eLoop.exec();

    disconnect(this,SIGNAL(threadsAreDone()),&eLoop,SLOT(quit()));
}
```

Comment: Local events loops are a completely inappropriate way to make asynchronous code appear synchronous. They are probably the most evil and pain-inducing construct in Qt I know of (as everything can happen before the exec() returns - leaving the application in an inconsistent unexpected state; just an example: "this" could be deleted). Using them without knowing exactly what one is doing will cause horror and pain in the long run. Better make the getAction() API asynchronous.

Comment: yes if one of them makes an error that loop will wait wait  is better adding a timer to detect abnormal latency?